# Cannot start build of Jenkins pipeline due to remoting version issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have updated Jenkins version to 2.346.3 (from 2.289) and now pipeline does not get started once build is initiated and giving this error in pipeline console log.

```
Jenkins error FATAL: Rejecting the connection because the Remoting version is older than the minimum required version (3.14).
To allow the connection anyway, set the hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.allowUnsupportedRemotingVersions system property to true.
```

We have controller Jenkins node and aggent nodes in AWS ECS cluster. Required EC2 components are already starting in AWS end when pipeline is triggered. And connectivity to them is working from Jenkins end. But cannot connected agent to AWS ECS cluster.  We verified that when we run command manually in Jenkins server to connect agent.jar, pipeline starts building.

Jenkins controller node OS is Ubuntu 20 and Java version is OpenJDK 1.8

This was working in all previous Jenkins version and doesn't seem to be any issue with permissions related to security groups. ECS plugin used to connect Jenkins controller to agent is "Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) / Fargate" which is updated to its latest version and configs are same as previous versions.

When pipeline starts, relevant EC2 slave instance starts from AWS end and Jenkins logs says "waiting agent to connect".

Anything can do to initiate pipeline build?

Comment: Did you read the [Upgrade guides](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/]) ? It [warns you](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.346/#reject-connections-from-unsupported-agent-versions). And even the error tells you what to do!

Comment: Yes, but it couldn't tell how to do it. And I couldn't find the path where "hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.allowUnsupportedRemotingVersions" property resides.

Answer (score 0):

The reported error is: `Remoting version is older than the minimum required version (3.14)`

The offered workaround is:

> To allow the connection anyway, set the
> `hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.allowUnsupportedRemotingVersions` system
> property to true.

Jenkins System Properties are set at launch. The [Jenkins Features Controlled with System Properties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/) describes the invocation.

> **Usage**
> System properties are defined by passing `-Dproperty=value` to the `java`
> command line to start Jenkins. Make sure to pass all of these
> arguments **before** the `-jar` argument, otherwise they will be ignored.

However, the above should not be considered your first resolution step. Any time you are upgrading Jenkins, the correct procedure is to:

1. Update all the plugin to the latest compatible version
2. **Read the LTS [Upgrade Guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/) and/or [Changelog](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog/) for your release**
3. Consider and take appropriate actions
4. Make a backup !! (And preferably validate on a non-Production instance first)
5. Upgrade Core
6. Upgrade plugins
7. Validate
8. If not at latest, go to step 1.

If you followed these steps (ie: step 2), you'd have found [2.303.x](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.303/#upgrading-to-jenkins-lts-2-303-x) added certain remoting hardening, and [2.346.x](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.346/#reject-connections-from-unsupported-agent-versions), "Reject connections from unsupported agent versions".

The preferred course of action is of course not to `allowUnsupportedRemotingVersions`, rather to roll-out a [Supported Remoting Version](https://www.jenkins.io/projects/remoting/). As noted in the [Remoting source repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci/remoting/blob/master/README.md#downloads),

> **Downloads**
> Jenkins Remoting libraries are supplied as a part of the Jenkins distributions, and it is recommended to use versions from there to ensure compatibility with your Jenkins instance.  You can download the `${JENKINS_URL}/jnlpJars/agent.jar` from your Jenkins server. If you  need a specific Remoting version, it can be downloaded from the Jenkins artifact repository. Recent artifacts are available [here](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/releases/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting).
>
> For usage in Docker, the Jenkins project also provides official agent images which bundle Remoting: [jenkins/agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/agent) and [jenkins/inbound-agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/inbound-agent). We recommend using and extending these images if you need to run agents in Docker.

The above should get you operational again.

---

**WARNING :**
Per [2.361.x Upgrade Guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.361/), Jenkins now [requires Java 11 to run](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/06/28/require-java-11/). The recommendation is to go with an OpenJDK, eg: [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=11). It also moves from using System V `init` to `systemd` services on [Linux installation packages](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/03/25/systemd-migration/).

Be sure to read the documentation and guidance before proceeding. **Key**: Do not upgrade via UI if previously installed via Package Manager.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the response. I have downloaded latest remoting version jar. But I wonder where and how to replace it with current one. I couldn't find the location where remoting jar needs to be placed. Could you please help?

Comment: If your system is running (so revert if you have to), you'll find the existing path for the agent.jar under `/computer/<nodename>/systemInfo`, The value for `sun.java.command`. Location depends on whether you are using [docker-agent](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/), [running manullay](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/), etc.

Comment: Hi, I got to know that remoting jar is not executing on Jenkins-master server by its own. So where do I replace this jar. ?  We have AWS ECS cluster where slaves start when a pipeline triggers and it's (remoting jar and communication between slave) is managed by SSH Build Agents plugin. I couldn't find any option to select the agent version in SSH build agent plugin or AWS ECS Fargate plugins. Can you explain it bit more please?

Comment: I don't use AWS. How do did you build your [agent image](https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecs/#plugin-content-agent)? You probably need to update the image then.  What does your node's log (`<JENKINS_URL>/computer/<nodename>log say for `[SSH] Starting slave process` ? That would tell you where the current agent launches.

Comment: Or have you just tried to bring it up by relaunching Jenkins with `-Dhudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.allowUnsupportedRemotingVersions=true` first, then you can inspect things.